Stop rotate/move view from being jumpy?
While rotating or panning my view I notice it jumps a lot. Like I'm rotating and all of the sudden I'm upside-down on the complete opposite side of what I was just trying to look at. I don't know if there's a way I can stop it from happening or if I can control my view another way, but it's very annoying and adds a lot of time cause I have to re-orient myself every 5 minutes. Walk/fly mode is pretty nice but needing to click 3 buttons just to move isn't helpful either.



Could you possibly be pressing keys by accident while rotating?

Do you try to lock the view to the 3D cursor ? To do so, press N in the 3D Viewport, and open the "View" tab. Check the View Lock/Lock/To 3D Cursor button. You can adjust the 3D cursor position on your object with Shift+RMB (Set 3D Cursor).

I tried locking my view to the 3d cursor but it doesnt seen to affect the jumping at all.

What about the size of your object ? Is it very small or very large ? Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?
